# Rails 3.1 and MySQL Mysql::Error: Incorrect string value:

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I keep getting an incorrect string value error in my Rake Task when I go to insert into my DB for one specific record. I tried converting it to UTF8 after reading several posts here on it but still have not resolved the issue (no guarantee I did that right). Any thoughts on what else it could be? Anything I left out?

MySQL Server Community 5.5

Conversion Code:

```
  ic = Iconv.new('UTF-8//IGNORE', 'UTF-8')

  @summary = ic.iconv(bug.summary << ' ')[0..-2]
```

Create Code:

```
JiraBug.create(
              :issue => bug.key,
              :summary => @summary,
              :reporter_name => reporter_name,
              :assignee_name => assignee_name,
              :weight => weight,                                                                                            :issue_created => issue_created,
              :issue_updated => issue_updated,
              :jira_it_division_id => @it_division_id,
              :jira_project_id => @project_id,
              :jira_priority_id => @priority_id,
              :jira_status_id => @status_id,
              :jira_originating_phase_id => @originating_phase_id,
              :jira_detection_phase_id => @detection_phase_id,
              :jira_version_id => @version_id,
              :jira_version_name => @version_name,
              :death_burrito_application_id => @jira_id
          )
```

Offending String:

> "Instance Blueprints → aa-test-kim → Module/Domain Objects - there is
>   a drop down title \"ID [REMOVEME]\".  I don't think the 'removeme'
>   belongs."

Error

> Mysql::Error: Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x86\x92 aa...' for column
>   'summary' at row 1: INSERT INTO `jira_bugs` (`assignee_name`,
>   `created_at`, `death_burrito_application_id`, `issue`,
>   `issue_created`, `issue_updated`, `jira_detection_phase_id`,
>   `jira_it_division_id`, `jira_originating_phase_id`,
>   `jira_priority_id`, `jira_project_id`, `jira_status_id`,
>   `jira_version_id`, `jira_version_name`, `reporter_name`, `summary`,
>   `updated_at`, `weight`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)   [1m[35m (1.0ms)[0m  ROLLBACK Mysql::Error:
>   Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x86\x92 aa...' for column 'summary' at
>   row 1: INSERT INTO `jira_bugs` (`assignee_name`, `created_at`,
>   `death_burrito_application_id`, `issue`, `issue_created`,
>   `issue_updated`, `jira_detection_phase_id`, `jira_it_division_id`,
>   `jira_originating_phase_id`, `jira_priority_id`, `jira_project_id`,
>   `jira_status_id`, `jira_version_id`, `jira_version_name`,
>   `reporter_name`, `summary`, `updated_at`, `weight`) VALUES (?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up doing a record specific hack for right now.

```
@summary = bug.summary.gsub(/→/,'>')
```

Not the greatest solution but until I find a better way this will have to do